# Previous 12 month with TO_CHAR

Tags: sql, to-char

How can I correctly write the WHERE filter to only get results from the previous 12 months if I only want to consider year-month?

```
SELECT
to_char(received_date, 'YYYY-MM')
FROM table1
WHERE to_char(received_date, 'YYYY-MM') #---->from now, previous 12 month 
GROUP BY to_char(received_date, 'YYYY-MM')
```

Comment: tag your database as well

Comment: just do date math against current date - 12 and then cast to your to_char.